# Why won't my program run the code all the way to the last print call? (Python)

Tags: python

I am a newcomer to programming, still learning and probably missing some easy mistake here. The code runs perfectly fine, until it is supposed to `"print the last print" (printf"\nHello, {formatted_name}!"))`, which it does not do unfortunately... As I said, I am probably missing something obvious here, I'd appreciate the help. I have tried both def...(): and def...(f_name, l_name) none seems to work the way I wish.

```
def get_formatted_name(f_name, l_name): / def get_formatted_name():

    while True:
        print("\nPlease tell me your name:")
        print("(enter 'q' at any time to quit)")
        
        f_name = input("First name: ")
        if f_name == 'q':
            break
        l_name = input("Last name: ")
        if l_name == 'q':
            break

        formatted_name = get_formatted_name(f_name, l_name)
        print(f"\nHello, {formatted_name}!")
```

Comment: can you show the code for get_formatted_name2

Comment: "*The code runs perfectly fine*": Then what output *do* you get? What input did you enter? Because inputting `q` will `break` your `while` loop, so the rest of the code after that will never be executed.

Comment: share what you get on calling ```get_formatted_name2```, Is it a error? or share the code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I love Muffin Knight. It will only be possible to help you if you edit your question to include a [mcve]. You might also find it beneficial to take the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get the most out of the site.

Comment: sorry, the "2" was by accident, I took it out now. When run my code and put in my name or q, this comes out:

Please tell me your name:
(enter 'q' at any time to quit)
First name: muffin
Last name: knight

Please tell me your name:
(enter 'q' at any time to quit)
First name: q

Hello, None!



So it basically keeps on asking for a new name and when i want to break by typing "q" it greets me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `formatted_name = get_formatted_name(f_name, l_name)` you are in fact calling the function you are in from within itself. it is what's called a `recursion`. to fix your issue I believe you want to replace the line with:

```
formatted_name = f_name + " " + l_name
```

or another way using `format`:

```
formatted_name = "{} {}".format(f_name, l_name)
```

using `fstring`:

```
formatted_name = f"{f_name} {l_name}"
```

You might want to read up on [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) to understand it better

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of an expert with Python, but here's my two cents:

1. `formatted_name = get_formatted_name(f_name, l_name)` starts the whole process again, which means it never gets to the last `print` statement.
   It loops the same function over and over until the user enters "q" as either their first or last name, in which case it doesn't reach `print` in any possible case.
   Notice that the function asking for the user's `input` and the one You're trying to `print` out the user's name with are the same - recursion.
2. `while True:` seems pointless to me, unless you're practicing and learning Python. The code keeps asking the user for their first and last names, even if they give them both. Only way to `break` out of the `while` loop is to enter "q" as either name.

My fix, if you could call it that:

with `while` loop:

```
def get_formatted_name():
    f_name = ""
    l_name = ""

    while not f_name and not l_name:
        print("\nPlease tell me your name:")
        print("(enter 'q' at any time to quit)")
    
        f_name = input("First name: ")
        if f_name == 'q':
            break
        l_name = input("Last name: ")
        if l_name == 'q':
            break

    print(f"\nHello, {f_name} {l_name}!")
```

without `while`, the very basic for learning and practicing:

```
def get_formatted_name():
    print("\nPlease tell me your name:")
    print("(enter 'q' at any time to quit)")
    
    f_name = input("First name: ")
    l_name = input("Last name: ")

    print(f"\nHello, {f_name} {l_name}!")
```

Using `while` version is probably better, since You can be assured the user enters both name or can opt out of entering either.

Comment: Thanks for your help as well! Your code also works perfectly fine, but I figured after trying both yours and @ExtraFishness code, his is would ask me for a name every time until I actually break by typing "q". Yours would only ask me for a name once before stopping automatically. Aynhow, thanks for helping :)